# Trying to parse string value from XML file from <IDNAME>FILE WITH SPACES </IDNAME>. I needing only the file name

Tags: parsing

Playlist file name needs parsed from idname tag. I want to pipe all the files names into a new row for each file name.

I understand a little about cmd commands FOR /F tokens and delemias %%P DO if.
I am not figuring out though how to parse through the xml document correctly.

Here is the xml.

[!example xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOG12.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOG12.png)

for /F tokens^=1^ delims^>^<^= %%a in (TEST.lpl) do ( if "%%a" equ "IDNAME" echo %%a > filelist.txt
%%a was unexpected at this time.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and add relevant tags.